# Round function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to round a decimal number with 4 digit(e.g 4.3333) Is there any code in javascript?

I tried the following code

```
var dec=round(4.3234323,4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code

```
var num= 4.3234323;
var dec=(num).toFixed(4);
```

Answer (score 6):

There is `.toFixed(n)` method for number:

```
var dec = 4.3234323.toFixed(4);
```

And note `4.toFixed(4)` will cause syntax error, you have to wrap it like `(4).toFixed(4)` or `4..toFixed(4)`,

it's always safe to used on a vairiable as `var dec = num.toFixed(4);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var someValue = 4.3234323;
var decimalVal = someValue.toFixed(4);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For rounding the number, you can use -

```
var num = 4.3234323;
parseFloat(Math.ceil( num * 10 ) / 10).toFixed(4)
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Da9tz/26/)

OR you only want to take value at four decimal points then use -  [`.toFixed(n)`](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1013-javascript-number-tofixed-method.htm)